# Работа с List,Java

Tags: java, list, итераторы

Нужно из большого списка ,примерно миллион элементов ,оставить первые 1000 а остальное удалить.Как наиболее оптимальнее сделать это?

Answer (score 2):

```
 int size=myList.size();  //myList - ваш список
 List<Integer> subList=myList.subList(1000, size); //выделяем под список от 1000 до конца
 subList.clear(); //удаляем весь подсписок
```

P.S. Подсписок это не новый список, а некий вью на ваш основной список, копия не создается.

Answer (score 0):

Ну если уж через итератор, как свидетельствует тэг, то завести счетчик на 1К и при каждой итерации уменьшать его. Соответственно, элементы копировать в другой список пока счетчик не достигнет 0.

Comment: с итератором автор явно погорячился, он не для этого нужен. а лист такое  умеет делать из коробки : list.subList(startAt, endAt); так получите список нужных. а чтобы именно удалить можно с помощью removeIf, передав соответствующие условие в аргумент

Comment: не обязательно через итератор,хотелось бы не создавать новый список,а в данном списке просто удалить все последующие после 1000 элемента

Comment: Спасибо Дмитрий